# ssh: Could not resolve hostname docker-ip onos1: No address associated with hostname

Tags: ssh

after typing the command

ssh -p 8101 karaf@'docker-ip onos1' #password is karaf

I am getting an error

ssh: Could not resolve hostname docker-ip onos1: No address associated with hostname

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is several reason of why it's not working

1. An hostname cannot contains space. More information of valid hostname are available here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname
2. If you are trying to reach the ssh from a docker and you opened the port (probably with -p 8101:22), you have then to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead. You command will be `ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost`. If you are trying to connect on another host, simply use the IP address of this remote host.
3. If you like to enter in a running docker in command line, it may be more simple to use `docker exec -ti <docker_id> bash`. Replace the  by the Docker ID founded with `docker ps` command.